# Relative Positioning with TikZ-UML does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

To create a TikZ component diagram, I use TikZ-UML ([https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=download](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ekielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=download)). For relative positioning, I position my `umlbasiccomponent`s with `right=1.5cm of component-body.east` (like described in  [Tikz UML relative positioning problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423048/tikz-uml-relative-positioning-problems)) . While the component itself gets aligned correctly, the heading is aligned wrong, as demonstrated here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\usetheme[compress]{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Komponenten}
  \begin{tikzpicture}    
    \begin{umlcomponent}[name=peass]{Peass} 
      \umlbasiccomponent[anchor=west, name=dependency,  fill=white]{Dependency}
      \umlbasiccomponent[right=1.5cm of dependency-body.east, name=measurement, fill=white]{Measurement}
    \end{umlcomponent}  
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: wrong positioning of Measurement-tag]

Is there any way to align both, text and the frame of the component, correctly?

Comment: The size of the `Peass` is also wrong. You can of course do `\umlbasiccomponent[x=5, name=measurement, fill=white]{Measurement}`, but then you don't get the relative position.

Comment: Yes, the examples of tikz-uml make use of the absolute positioning. But I want to define the relations (e.g. Measurement is left of Dependency) and be able to change the concrete positioning afterwards by setting spacing etc.. Therefore, I want to use relative positions.

Answer (score 1):

One (not very nice) solution is to use umldocument (https://github.com/maybeec/tikz-uml-component-diagram.git) instead, which easily allows relative positioning:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{SeaGreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.8,0.1}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,
  shapes,
  positioning,
  calc,
  decorations.markings,
  decorations.pathreplacing,
  decorations.text,
  decorations.pathmorphing,
  decorations.shapes
}


\usepackage{umldocument}
\usepackage{umlmultidocument}
\usepackage{umlcomponent}

\usetheme[compress]{Berlin}

\tikzset{
    doc/.style={umldocument, align=center, text width=1.5cm, minimum height=2.5cm},
    multdoc/.style={umlmultidocument, align=center, text width=1.5cm, minimum height=2.5cm},
    comp/.style={umlcomponent, align=center, text width=2cm, minimum height=1.0cm},
    comment/.style={umldocument,fill=SeaGreen, text width=1.7cm, minimum height=.7cm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[comp] (dependency) {Dependency};
    \node[right=of dependency, comp] (measurement) {Measurement};
    \node[right=of measurement, comp] (analysis) {Analysis};

    \node[comp, right=-0.5cm of dependency.west, minimum width=10cm, fill opacity=0.0, text opacity=1.0, text depth=1.5cm] (peass) {Peass};  
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Since this is not an exact solution, I'll accept a solution using tikz-uml and/or preserving the splitted components, but for now, this is a viable workaround.